# Material UI Accordion title text overflowing out of the container

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI accordion. Inside `AccordionSummary` component where title should be placed I am creating a flex layout with two flex items.

The first flex item contains accordion title while second flex item has some buttons. The second flex item has fixed width and I want rest of space occupied by the first flex item.

So here width of first flex item is dynamic which is based on the width of accordion which in turn depends on screen size.

Now I want the title to shown as text ellipsis if title text length is more than available flex space but in practicle that is not the case. When title text is long it overflows out from the `Accordion` component and even content of second flex item also overflows

It's complicated to put my project code here so I have reproduced it in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-overflow-b8144?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide width if you're using `noWrap`, I have created [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-overflow-forked-9ferd) fork with a required fix. Check the description of `noWrap` [here](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/) for further details